# ARIMA predicts the one step ahead of the actual prediction

Tags: time-series, arima

[image: Prediction is Red and actual value in Blue]

[image: PACF GRAPH]
[image: ACF GRAPH]

I have a time series dataset. When I build an ARIMA model, the model forecasts the values that are ahead of actual data points. What is wrong with my model.

I used grid search to fit the model ARIMA (5,0,1).

Comment: If I understand your plot correctly (fitted vs actual data), this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: You can see that by yourself by, i.e., assuming an AR(1) model, say, $Y_t = 0.9 Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$, and plotting the true vs fitted variables. But, by definition, predicted $\hat Y_{t+1}$ will be $\hat Y_{t+1} = \hat \alpha Y_{t}$

Comment: Thanks for replying! Does not my chart imply that the model is making prediction for tomorrow on the basis of value that is observed today? I do not think this is the expected behaviour. Can you provide me with some helpful links that suggests that this is the normal behaviour?

Comment: Well, it is _the_ definition of ARIMA, to model future based on the past values. Naturally, the forecast of $Y_{t+1}$ (tomorrow) will be based on the historic values of $(Y_t, Y_{t-1}, \ldots)$, including today. For concrete example, [see here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-forecasting.html). Try writing down the equations of some AR(1) (or your ARIMA(5,0,1), if you want) as in the example, plug in some estimates and known data ($Y_t$) and see how do the forecasts look like. Reading up on _the lag operator_ might be useful too.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I get that the forecasts will be based on historic values. But if the values are exactly the same for time t and t-1, what is the use of the model? I can do that without the use of the model.

Comment: In your graph it doesn't seem that they are _exactly_ the same. But yes, this can occur, read up on "unit roots". In your case its likely that $\alpha_1$ gets estimated very close to 1, so you get $Y_{t+1} = 0.98 Y_{t} + ...$. For this reason one often stationarizes the data (for example, by taking differences of the data), since ARMA models a stationary process. Also, the "I" part of ARIMA is one way of handling the stationarity within the model, so you can try, i.e., ARIMA(p,1,q) models. (Sorry for not writing this rigorously, but hope you get the idea)

Comment: Also, it wouldn't hurt reading many other chapters [here in otext](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html), they cover the basics really well.

Comment: I used augmented dicky fuller test to confirm that the series is stationary.

Comment: ADF test under wrong conditions may give very false positives. However, while in a hurry, I don't have the links to prove it